# C Socket program to create Hive Query Authentication service

Tags: c

I am new to C Socket programming and trying to establish a client username and password authentication service in  a known server. Client here are the users having username The authentication service will have a thread keep state with the spawned Hive Server(HIVE in Hadoop)  to terminate the server in disuse, after error, or in termination with the authorization service. Can I get any code snippet for it plsss? :)

Answer (score 0):

C socket programming depends on the platform you are developing for. Is it Windows? UNIX? Before implementing any advanced code such as an authentication procedure you should train with simple socket programs. For UNIX (Linux, specifically) systems you can find some socket theory and examples [here](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm).